# how to keep app active or restart when killed?

Tags: android, background

I'm trying to create an app that sets an alarm if the screen is off for too long. This will be checked in the background every 5 minutes. Unfortunately android kills my app sometimes and I need to keep my app active in the background. What is the best way to do this?

I was also thinking about restarting every 5 minutes if the app is killed. Is this a better way to keep my app mostly active in the background? How to do this? Or is there a better solution for me?

Maybe restarting the way like Facebook does?

Comment: Use a [Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) .

Comment: Have you tried setting it as a background services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i fixed it by using a simple service that does nothing except for an infiit loop of logging.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend having a look at Mark Murphy's [WakefulIntentService.](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful)